# Buscar palabras en una frase

Tags: r, regex

¿Se puede encontrar dos palabras en una frase?

Por ejemplo

```
section <- c("pepe juan marta ana", "maria ana pepe pepa", "pepe marta dina tania"," juan roberto tania")
grade <- c(78, 93, 56, 23)
gradebook <- data.frame(section, grade)
```

```
  section                     grade
pepe juan marta ana              78
maria ana pepe pepa              93
pepe ana marta dina tania        56
juan roberto tania               23
```

Quiero encontrar la palabra "juan"

```
mutate(gradebook, buscar = ifelse( str_detect(gradebook$section ,"juan"), "contiene","no sale"))
```

```
   section             grade     buscar
pepe juan marta ana      78     contiene
maria ana pepe pepa      93     no sale
pepe marta dina tania    56     no sale
juan roberto tania       23     contiene
```

Ha encontrado la palabra "juan" entre los nombres

Ahora quiero buscar dos nombres:

```
mutate(gradebook, buscar = ifelse( str_detect(gradebook$section ,c("ana","roberto")), "contiene","no sale"))
```

```
 section                 grade     buscar
pepe juan marta ana       78       contiene
maria ana pepe pepa       93       no sale
pepe marta dina tania     56       no sale
juan roberto tania        23       contiene
```

ana sale en la segunda fila pero no lo detecta.

- ¿cómo sería para detectar dos nombres de forma individual?

  Si quiero buscar ana y roberto, el resultado deseado sería:

```
 section                 grade     buscar
pepe juan marta ana       78       contiene
maria ana pepe pepa       93       contiene
pepe marta dina tania     56       no sale
juan roberto tania        23       contiene
```

- ¿cómo seria para detectar dos nombres a la vez en la misma frase?

  Por ejemplo buscar tania y juan

```
 section                 grade     buscar
pepe juan marta ana       78       no sale
maria ana pepe pepa       93       no sale
pepe marta dina tania     56       no sale
juan roberto tania        23       contiene
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema es intentas usar múltiples patrones independientes con `str_detect()` y la función solo espera uno. Puedes lograr lo mismo, buscar alguna de las palabras deseadas, desde un único patrón regular, indicando el `|` como `OR` lógico, es decir: `ana|roberto`:

```
gradebook %>% 
  mutate(buscar = ifelse(str_detect(section, "ana|roberto"), "contiene","no sale"))
```

Si quieres la ocurrencia de dos palabras, no importa el orden de la mismas, puede hacer algo parecido a lo anterior, y plantear dos patrones, con las posibles combinaciones:

```
gradebook %>% 
  mutate(buscar = ifelse(str_detect(section, "juan.*tania|tania.*juan"), 
                         "contiene","no sale"))
```